# Application of matrix fuctions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given some $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix^i$ it is possible to define $f(A) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iA^i$ that converges under some conditions.

A classical application for this is for linear systems of ODE's. If $x'(t) = Ax(t)$ then $x(t) = e^{At}x_o$.

My question is: are there other applications that make use of some matrix function? (not necessarily $e^A$, but also $\sqrt{A}$, $\ln(A)$ etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the idea of applying functions to matrices/operators in this way is called [functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus).

Some important examples:

- $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is very important in the study of positive semi-definite matrices/operators.  An absolutely essential fact to the study of positive semi-definite matrices is that if $A$ is a bounded positive operator, then there is a unique positive $\sqrt{A}$ satisfying $(\sqrt{A})^2 = A$, which necessarily commutes with $A$.  More generally, one needs the square root function in order to express the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of a matrix, wherein *any* matrix $A$ can be written in the form
  $$
  A = U\sqrt{A^*A}
  $$
  for some unitary (orthogonal) $U$.  (Note: $A^*$ is the "conjugate transpose" of $A$, which is just the transpose when $A$ is real).
- $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is very important to the study of [Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) and [Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra).  Both of these may be thought of in terms of matrices... most of the time.  Importantly, the function $e^x$ takes us from the Lie Algebra to the corresponding Lie Group, while $\ln(x)$ takes us from the Lie Group to the corresponding Lie Algebra.  In a sense, we can think of this as an extension of the usual ODE application of $e^x$.
- $f(x) = 1/x$ (or more typically, $f(x) = 1/(\lambda - x)$) comes up a lot.  A very common (and useful!) trick is to note that whenever the series for $f(x) = 1/x$ converges, the matrix $f(A)$ must be the inverse of $A$, which means that $A$ has to be invertible.  In [matrix/operator perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_perturbation), it is often helpful to characterize the eigenvalues of an operator $T$ using contour integrals in the complex plane of the form
  $\int_\Gamma \frac{1}{\xi - T} d\xi = \int_{\Gamma} (\xi I - T)^{-1} d\xi$.